# HarRequest.Postdata() returning NULL - JAVA + SELENIUM+BROWSER PROXY

Tags: java

I'm currently working on Selenium to automate a web testing framework
For HTTP traffic , i am using browsermob proxy
I am getting the POST,GET commands correctly  through har classes

But on a post command with correct post data , i'm not able to track the post data, It returns NULL

I'm using getPostData() for this
Can you please help me on this
Will getPostData() returns the actual post data

Code Snippet :

```
    System.out.println("getting the HAR data");
    har = server.getHar();
    if(har==null){
    System.out.println("Har is NULL");
    }
    HarLog harLog = har.getLog(); 
    List<HarEntry> logEntries = harLog.getEntries(); 
    System.out.println("getting the HAR data");
    String httpgetMethod =null;
    String posttext=null,postFileName=null,postContentType=null,postName=null,postValue=null;
    harRequest = new HarRequest();

    for (HarEntry harEntry : logEntries){ 
        //Retrieve the Request values
        org.browsermob.core.har.HarResponse response = harEntry.getResponse();   

        org.browsermob.core.har.HarRequest harRequest = harEntry.getRequest();
        if (response == null){ 
            System.out.println("Null response - "+harRequest.getUrl()); 
                continue; 
        } 


        int status = response.getStatus(); 
        httpgetMethod  = harRequest.getMethod();
        System.out.println(harRequest.getUrl()+" - "+status); 
        System.out.println("Method = "+httpgetMethod);

        if (httpgetMethod.equals("POST"))
            {
            postdata1 = harRequest.getPostData(); //HERE I AM GETTING NULL INSTEAD:-(
            if (postdata1!=null){
            System.out.println("Hurray!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!postdata!=null");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("postdata is null");
            }
        }

        if (httpgetMethod.equals(postcommand) && (postdata1!=null)){

            try{
            posttext =postdata1.getText();
            }

            catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (posttext == null){ 
                System.out.println("Post Data NULL"); 
                //continue; 
            } 
            else{
            System.out.println("postdata text = "+posttext);
            }


            if (((HarPostDataParam) postdata1.getParams()).getFileName() != null)
            System.out.println("postFileName = "+((HarPostDataParam) postdata1.getParams()).getFileName());
            if (((HarPostDataParam) postdata1.getParams()).getContentType() != null)
                System.out.println("getContentType = "+((HarPostDataParam) postdata1.getParams()).getContentType());
            if (((HarPostDataParam) postdata1.getParams()).getName() != null)
                System.out.println("getName = "+((HarPostDataParam) postdata1.getParams()).getName());
            if (((HarPostDataParam) postdata1.getParams()).getValue() != null)
            System.out.println("getValue = "+((HarPostDataParam) postdata1.getParams()).getValue());
             List<HarPostDataParam> postdataparams = postdata1.getParams();
            for(HarPostDataParam posdatap : postdataparams)
            {
                 postFileName=posdatap.getFileName();
                 postContentType = posdatap.getContentType();
                 postName = posdatap.getName();
                 postValue=posdatap.getValue();
                 if ((postFileName) != null){ 
                    System.out.println("postFileName = "+postFileName); 

                 } 
                 else{
                    System.out.println("postFileNameis NULL");
                    }
                 if ((postContentType) != null){ 
                    System.out.println("postContentType = "+postContentType); 
                 }
                 else{
                    System.out.println("postContentType  is NULL");
                    } 
                 if ((postName) != null){ 
                    System.out.println("postName = "+postName); 

                   } 
                 else{
                    System.out.println("postName  is NULL");
                    } 
                 if ((postValue) != null){ 
                        System.out.println("postValue = "+postValue); 

                    } 
                 else{
                        System.out.println("postValue  is NULL");
                     } 
            }


} }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone reply on this please 
harRequest.getMethod(); gives POST command , but 
harRequest.getPostData() is always giving NULL instead

Comment: During the POST command , postdataparams is having size zero , meaning
it doesnt contain any valid data postdataparams.size()=0
Any insight on this plz?

Comment: Hi Guys
Have anyone integrated har library with webdriver in java and successfully got the POSTDATA for a POST command
I tried dumping the data to a .har file directly.
Still i can see only the POST command has been send , but the data went along with it is missing in the har file 
my code is 
 Har har = server.getHar(); 
     try { har.writeTo(new File("c:\\test1.har")); 
     } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     { e.printStackTrace();
     }

hope someone could reply please

thanks
robin

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem yesterday.
Downloaded latest sources of Browsermob-proxy from repository, builded them and post data contains all POSTed params now :-)